# calculating Linear value for a 0.5 binned data

Tags: r, extrapolation

Let suppose we have x and y axis , where x has value with 0.5 binning ,Let suppose i want to identify the y value for x =6.1 , How we can compute that.
firstly i thought running an LM function and having coefficient accordingly but the result isnt matching the expected one . guid me on this

[image]

Here is reproducible data set for the same , i want to calculate the values for `every 0.1 x value bin and find y value for the same`.

```
i5 <- data.frame(X= c(3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9.0,9.5,10,10.5,11,11.5,12,12.5,13,13.5,14, 14.5,15),

Y= c(10.3545454545455,  56.7181818181818,   127.160416666667,   211.811724137931,   338.958275862069,   460.078085106383,   586.825098039216,   742.63, 927.216538461539,   1113.65,    1306.15,    1493.35,    1703.74632653061,   1838.68461538462,   1952.55,    2015.88333333333,   2060.3168,  2080.968,   2095.41829787234,   2113.79634615385,   2114.05306122449,   2122.9096,  2123.90724137931,   2123.90724137931))
```

Comment: Why do you say "but the result isnt matching"?

Comment: i was trying with actual interpolation formulae. with r this is really very simple . thank you . @salman i tryed with LM and it try to fit the best fit line may be i should add polynomial to follow exact result, but approx serve the purpose of mine.